# Javascript If List Element contains 'Whatever', don't display

Tags: javascript

I've got some code in html like

```
<li id="1"></li>
<li id="2">Whatever</li>
<li id="3"></li>
```

Is there any way I can make it so that if the li contains a piece of text, it won't be displayed, yet all the other lis will be unaffected?

Comment: how do you access the `<li>`s? By ID?

Comment: FYI, for maximum browser compatibility, an id should start with a letter, not a number.

Comment: @jfriend00 good call, its just a good practice in general to never start an ID or class with a number.

Comment: @jfriend00 That's just an example for an id, normally I'd use much more descriptive ones, but I didn't know about that actually so that might help me in the future :)

Answer (score 1):

You could loop through your `li`s and use `document.getElementById(id).innerHTML` to get the value inside it to compare to, and if so, `use document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';`

Answer (score 1):

```
var list = document.getElementsByTagName("li");

for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
    if(list[i].textContent === "Whatever"){
        list[i].style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/csUbn/)**

Comment: actually, is there any way I can make it so that the List Element can include more than just that one word, so for example at the moment it only works if it just includes 'Whatever', but I want it if it's 'Whatever word'?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a couple of examples using exact/non-exact matches, case-sensitive and insensitive.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZgrzL/

Edit: wow, I'm slow.